# Solution of the equation $\cot \theta = 2\cot 2\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, infinity, mathematica

I've tried to solve the equation $\cot \theta = 2\cot 2\theta$ with the  command 'Reduce' of Mathematica and obtained $\theta = n\pi$ as the solution with n an integer. But $\theta=n\pi$ is clearly a singularity in a cotangent function so this is puzzling.

I've realized that the above equation can be simplified to:
$\tan \theta=0$, and that is probably what Mathematica does to obtain the solution, but again, how $\theta=n\pi$ can be the solution if it is not in the domain of a $\cot$ function?
Is that an inconsistency in Mathematica or am I missing something?

Comment: +1) Computer software to do math is great, but not perfect. When you graph both curves, they "meet" at infinity at the angles suggested by Mathematica. When you solve the equation by converting it all into sines and cosines, there is a sine term in both numerators. If one would inadvertently cross multiply, the solutions of $sin\theta=0$ would appear...That's the best I see it...

Comment: `Reduce[Cot[t]==2Cot[2t],t,Reals]` gives as result `False` in Mathematica v. 10.3.

Comment: Thanks mickep that's interesting. I get the same result but when you remove 'Reals' the result is: $C[1] \[Element] Integers && t == \Pi C[1]$

Comment: @RutgerPrimrose It could be interesting to ask that question about Mathematica at mathematica.stackexchange.com. Maybe someone there knows how and why it is as it is in that software.

Comment: It is pretty clear for me now that the problem in Mathematica comes when you do not specify the domain but i cannot find a reason why it would be useful to have such a solution where the infinity is taken as a possible value in the domain of a function. So the question is more a technicality now and I will pass it to mathematica.stackexchange.com as you proposed. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Reciprocate both sides:

$$\tan(\theta)=\frac12\tan(2\theta)=\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{2\cos(2\theta)}$$

$$=\frac{2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{2\cos(2\theta)}=\frac{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{2\cos^2(\theta)-1}$$

$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$$

Which allows us to cancel the sines and move all the cosines to the right.

$$1=\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{2\cos^2(\theta)-1}$$

$$2\cos^2(\theta)-1=\cos^2(\theta)$$

$$\cos^2(\theta)-1=0$$

$$\cos(\theta)=\pm1$$

$$\theta=\pm n\pi$$

$$n=0,1,2,3,\dots$$

As I just noticed, along with the comments, is that the solution $\theta=\pm n\pi$ does not work for the original problem.

So, perhaps, I may note:

$$\lim_{\theta\to\pm n\pi}\cot(\theta)=\lim_{\theta\to\pm n\pi}2\cot(\theta)$$

Since the limit tends to be undefined, one notes that in a calculus sense, the problem is equivalent to:

$$\frac{2\cot(2\theta)}{\cot(\theta)}=1$$

And since the limit holds true, it is somewhat safe to say that is the answer.

However, take it as you will, accept the answer as correct if you want, there are no other "answers" other than maybe undefined.

Comment: But those values of $\theta$ are not solutions to the original equation $\cot \theta=2\cot2\theta$ (that has no real solutions), since neither the left-hand side nor the right-hand side are defined...

Comment: @mickep I just realized that.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand $\cot2\theta$, you get
$$
\cot\theta=\frac{\cot^2\theta-1}{\cot\theta}
$$
that's clearly an inconsistent equation.

On the other hand, if you rewrite it as
$$
\tan2\theta=2\tan\theta
$$
and expand, you get
$$
\frac{\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}=\tan\theta
$$
that has the solutions $\tan\theta=0$, but they aren't solutions of the original equation, unless you allow $\infty$ as a value.

Depending on its implementation and conventions, a piece of software can give different results from “inconsistent”.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: your equation is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{\cot(\theta)}=0$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{\cot(\theta)}$ is not an equation.

Comment: sorry i have fogotten $=0$

Comment: Why is that a hint? I've written above that $\tan \theta = 0$, which is the same thing. Points $n\theta$ solve that equation but the function $\cot \theta$ is not defined at those points. That's my concern.

Comment: $\tan(\theta)=0$ and $\frac{1}{\cot(\theta)}=0$ is not the same

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think the OP is confused, and elaborating may help him understand.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  I'm getting a little tired of seeing your name appearing under the Low Quality flag over and over, which seems to be almost every review I carry out. I don't understand why people keep flagging your answers. Hints are completely acceptable. They probably think that your answers are more suitable as comments. But how can anyone possibly make a distinction between a comment and an _answer_? Your answers are completely acceptable in my opinion and I will just keep hitting the "Looks OK" button. But more importantly why do you think that your answers keep getting flagged?

Comment: @BLAZE I think the problem with this answer was that it served to possibly confuse the OP (and possibly others) due to lack of explanation where I think an explanation would have been more preferable.  And the hint is somewhat vague.

Comment: @Simple Okay, thanks for explaining that; I was mainly addressing that this user nearly __always__ gets flagged as low quality. While in this case it is possibly justified; this user has given very reputable answers (albeit short in length) in the past.

Comment: @BLAZE Yes, while I now understand his answer, at the time of my post, I had not realized its significance.  I have a meta question concerning answers/hints/comments which you may find here:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22263/how-good-is-an-answer-without-any-explanation-and-how-far-should-an-explanation

Comment: @SimpleArt That's great, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @BLAZE No problem, judgement calls can be hard to make.